# D2W in Wonder Project doesn't show submenus

Tags: java, webobjects

I have a very simple `navigationMenu.plist` from one example in the Wonder site:

```
(    
    {
        name = Root;
        directActionClass = DirectAction;
        directActionName = default;
        children = "session.navigationRootChoice";
        childrenChoices = {
            home = (
                Posts,
                Authors,
            );
        };
    },
    {
        name = "Posts";
        action = "session.navController.listPostsAction";
        children = ("CreatePost","SearchPosts");
        conditions = ("context.hasSession");
    },
    {
        name = CreatePost;
        action = "session.navController.createPostAction";
    },
    {
        name = SearchPosts;
        action = "session.navController.searchPostsAction";
    },
    {
        name = Authors;
        action = "session.navController.listAuthorsAction";
        children = ("CreateAuthor","SearchAuthors");

    },
    {
        name = CreateAuthor;
        action = "session.navController.createAuthorAction";
    },
    {
        name = SearchAuthors;
        action = "session.navController.searchAuthorsAction";
    }
)
```

However, when I run the application, submenus are not shown. I am pretty sure this has to be a property that needs to be turned on. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought children was an array of strings. From one of my NavigationMenu.plist

```
{
    name = Root;
    children = ("Home","Person","Computer", "ComputerModels");
},
{
    name = "Home";
    action = "session.navController.homeAction";
},
{
    name = Person;
    action = "session.navController.listPersonAction";
    children = ("createPerson", "findPerson", "Logout");
},
{
    name = createPerson;
    action = "session.navController.createPersonAction";
},
{
    name = findPerson;
    action = "session.navController.findPersonAction";
}
```

Don't forget to set the navigationState rule in your rule model.

50 : pageConfiguration like '*Person' => navigationState = "Person" [com.webobjects.directtoweb.Assignment]

Comment: Thank you very much! It was indeed the navigationState rules.